# C# Remove duplicate lines in the contents of StringBuilder type

Tags: c#, duplicates, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a very large wordlist with each word in a separate line. I generate the words using some logic and storing them using StringBuilder. It appears in tests that I create some duplicated words e.g.

```
!AngryDogAngry1916!
@AngryAngryDog1916!
:AngryDog1916!
!AngryDogAngry1916!
...
```

In the example the generated first and fourth lines and I would like to remove one of them. How to remove the duplicate line(s) from the StringBuilder variable? Line-wise consideration is necessary, otherwise the words themselves would be manipulated e.g. modification of the word !AngryDogAngry1916! to !AngryDog1916! should NOT happen.
Thanks.

I could not find a method to access the content in a StringBuilder line-wise. I don't know where to start and do not to want to change the StringBuilder type.

Comment: Why are you using a StringBuilder in the first place as opposed to, say, an array or a `List<string>`? Or even better, a HashSet if you don't want duplicates?

Comment: It all has to go into a wordlist (text) file in a fast manner. HastSet will remove word duplicates if used with <string>, this is not allowed, I explained this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it :

```
StringBuilder strbuilder = new StringBuilder("!AngryDogAngry1916!\n@AngryAngryDog1916!\n:AngryDog1916!\n!AngryDogAngry1916!");
String[] splitstrings = strbuilder.ToString().Split('\n');
splitstrings = splitstrings.Distinct<String>().ToArray();
string result = string.Join("\n", splitstrings);
strbuilder.Clear();
strbuilder.Append(result);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Result:

```
!AngryDogAngry1916!
@AngryAngryDog1916!
:AngryDog1916!
```

othe way you must to call the function that removes repetition to the generation words method and then you can copy the results to the `StringBuilder`,adding your code to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

As one suggested in a comment, use `HashSet<T>` to store your words. This collection will help you detect duplicates using a complexity of O(1), which you won't be able to do with a `StringBuilder` instance.

`StringBuilder` is great for generating text on the fly, but it is not designed for efficient searching.

Since you mentioned you are worried about writing the output words in a *fast* manner while preserving the current implementation, you can still use an instance of `HashSet<T>` side-by-side with your `StringBuilder` for detecting duplicates. Thus, before appending your new word into your `StringBuilder` instance, you would check for duplicates using the hash set.

---

Following our discussion in the comments, if you *have to* deal with the fully filled `StringBuilder` instance, iterate over the resulting characters of the long string of words.

For each word (you recognize them when they end by the break line symbol(s) (`Environment.NewLine`)), add them into a `HashSet<string>` instance to detect duplicate entries.

When a duplicate is found, call the `StringBuilder.Remove` method to remove the word from the initial StringBuilder.

Comment: What type to consider for T in order to avoid the loss of information for example in order to prevent !AngryDogAngry1916! become e.g. !AngryDog1916    ? Is it possible to provide concrete implementation example ?

Comment: The concrete implementation mostly depends on how your program is written. In your case, you should consider `HashSet<string>`. I feel you don't utilize StringBuilder as one expects based on your question. Are you appending the word one by one, or are you editing an already fully filled StringBuilder instance?

Comment: Editing an already fully filled StringBuilder instance...

Comment: You should use the tip provided in my answer when you generate the words, i.e., before storing them in the `StringBuilder` instance. So, you don't end up analysing your fully filled instance.

Comment: The way I got the program delivered which is quite large from elsewhere that requires way many changes and deep dive into it. So, you mean there is no way to do this while editing an already fully filled StringBuilder instance.

Comment: I'm guiding you so that your application works efficiently. If you can modify the generation logic, this is the right way to go. Otherwise, this is more of a wacky approach/workaround. Having that said, if you _have to_ deal with the filled `StringBuilder` instance, you can iterate over it, fill a hash set instance and when you find a duplicate, crop that content.

Comment: @user1806967 I have edited my answer to provide you with an example of an algorithm to remove the duplicate entries from your `StringBuilder`.